# how to pass parameter for elasticsearch8 new java fluent api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i upgrade es java api from 7.9.3 to 8.5.3, i hava some problem compatibility code and don't know how to solve it, see me below code,
in preview code:

```
BoolQueryBuilder filterBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
 if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(searchDTO.getBrandId())) {
            String[] brands = searchDTO.getBrandId().split("*");
            filterBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(ATTR_BRAND_ID, brands));
 }
 if (Objects.nonNull(searchDTO.getRecommend())) {
            filterBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("recommend", searchDTO.getRecommend()));
 }
```

in new version i try as follows:

```
BoolQuery.of(e -> e.must(m -> m.terms(ts -> ts.field(ATTR_BRAND_ID).terms(s -> {
                List<FieldValue> fieldValues = Lists.newArrayList();
                Arrays.stream(brands).forEach(ele -> fieldValues.add(FieldValue.of(ele)));
                s.value(fieldValues);
                return s;
            }))).filter(f -> f.term(t -> t.field("recommend").value(searchDTO.getRecommend())))
```

The defect of the above code is that there is no non-null judgment,but unfortunately I don't know how to add non-empty conditional judgment in fluent-api.
Another question is as follows:
in preview code:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : valueMap.entrySet()) {
            filterBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(ATTR_PATH, QueryBuilders.matchQuery(ATTR_NAME, entry.getKey()), ScoreMode.None));
            BoolQueryBuilder shouldBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
            for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
                shouldBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(ATTR_PATH, QueryBuilders.matchQuery(ATTR_VALUE, s), ScoreMode.None));
            }
            filterBuilder.must(shouldBuilder);
        }
```

In the new version I try the following way,

```
BoolQuery.of(..)
.must(m -> {
                                Map<String, List<String>> valueMap = getValueMap(searchDTO);
                                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : valueMap.entrySet()) {
                                    m.nested(n -> n.path(ATTR_PATH).queryName(ATTR_NAME).query(q -> q.match(m1 -> m1.query(entry.getKey()))));
                                    for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
                                        m.nested(n -> n.path(ATTR_PATH).queryName(ATTR_VALUE).query(q -> {
                                            q.match(m1 -> m1.query(s));
                                            return q;
                                        }));
                                    }
                                }
                                return m;
                            })
```

But this way of writing is problematic. The original logic is the should query, but the should query needs to pass parameters. How to pass parameters in the new version of fluent-api should query, I don’t know how to implement it.

I am a novice in elasticsearch, can anyone who is familiar with elasticsearch give me an idea?

Comment: Hi there, what is the question? Please explain your problem statement in the beginning. You just started with some codes and in the end saying that it's related to Elasticsearch, so someone who reads the post gets lost very easily.

Comment: Yes, I will explain in detail. First of all, the first problem is that es java 8 api supports conditional splicing queries, 
e.g. 
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(clause...)) {
    filterBuilder. must(...));
} 
This is the es 7.9.3 version code. What needs to be spliced here is that the conditional judgment is established. 
Now upgrade to version 8.5.3 and modify as follows:   
BoolQuery.of(e -> e.must(...))
Here Missing condition judgment.how to add judgement?

Comment: Next question is a map,and iteratively splicing it, e.g.
for (Map.Entry entry : valueMap.entrySet()) {
    filterBuilder.must(...);
// Then splicing the value in the map
BoolQueryBuilder shouldBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
             for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
                shouldBuilder.should(..);
             }
             filterBuilder.must(shouldBuilder);
}
Now we upgrade to 8.5.3:
BoolQuery.of(..)
.must(m -> {
   for (Map.Entry entry : valueMap.entrySet()) {
    ...
}})
// How to pass the value here
.should(s -> {})

Comment: Please update your post with the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate via Builder. This example is from the first case, it will help to rewrite the second case.

```
var boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQuery.Builder();

        if (brands.length > 0) {
            List<FieldValue> fieldValues = Lists.newArrayList();
            Arrays.stream(brands).forEach(ele -> fieldValues.add(FieldValue.of(ele)));
            boolQueryBuilder.must(m -> m.terms(ts -> ts.field(ATTR_BRAND_ID).terms(v -> v.value(fieldValues))));
        }

        if (Objects.nonNull(recommend)) {
            boolQueryBuilder.filter(f -> f.term(t -> t.field("recommend").value(recommend)));
        }

        var boolQuery = boolQueryBuilder.build();
```